# "create if not exist" and "create table like" sql server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

how can i create a table just if that table is not exist. in my case, i want to create table with this query :

```
SELECT * 
INTO a
FROM b
```

that table a in db A and table b in db B. any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if not exists (select [name] from sys.tables where [name] = 'a') SELECT * 
INTO A.dbo.a
FROM B.dbo.b
```

you can try this .. its simple one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function for SQL Server.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('a') IS NULL
        SELECT *
        INTO a
        FROM b
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL, PostgreSQL, Sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_exists1 
(
   c1 TYPE
);
```

Oracle:

```
   DECLARE cnt NUMBER;
   BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = 'T_EXISTS1';
     IF cnt = 0 THEN 
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE t_exists1 
         (
           c1 TYPE
         );'; 
     END IF;
   END;
```

SQL Server:

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('t_exists1', 'U') IS NULL
  CREATE TABLE t_exists1 
  (
       c1 TYPE
  );
```